# Using link_to in an .erb file, concatenation syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concatenation, erb

1. In index.html.erb, I want a link that looks like the following for each college:  **Apply - $25**
2. I want the price displayed to change based on the value of college.undergrad_app_fee.

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work. Perhaps there's a special concatenation syntax to combine the explicit 'Apply -' with the price, or I need to escape <%= %> somehow, or there's a special way to do this with link_to?

```
   <td><%= link_to 'Apply - ' college.undergrad_app_fee, college.application_url %></td>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the string interpolation syntax:

```
<td><%= link_to "Apply - #{college.undergrad_app_fee}", college.application_url %></td>
```

As a bonus, if you only have the raw price, you can format it using `number_to_currency`:

```
<td><%= link_to "Apply - #{number_to_currency(college.undergrad_app_fee)}", college.application_url %></td>
```

**Follow up:**

For conditional links, use [link_to_if](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if) or [link_to_unless](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless), they should be relatively straightforward to use.

Handling the `nil` case for the currency formatting is a bit trickier. You can use the `||` operator to do it.

Combining the two methods would give this:

```
<td><%= link_to_if college.application_url, "Apply - #{number_to_currency(college.undergrad_app_fee || 0)}", college.application_url %></td>
```

Using the rails console is a good way to test the behaviours of the different helpers. You can access them through the `helper` object, for example:

```
> helper.number_to_currency(12)
 => "12,00 €"
> nil || 0
 => 0
> 12 || 0
 => 12
```

Comment: Wow, great answer - and fast, too! Thanks.  I'll mark your answer as the correct one.  I have a follow up question if you're up for it:  If college.undergrad_app_fee is null, I want it to show $0.  If college.application_url is null, I don't want it to be a link.  Any ideas?